# p_split help in string?

Tags: php

```
<?PHP 
SMARTTAG('<PHP:DataSource ID="DataSource1" CommandText="SELECT * FROM login" Adapter="Adapter1"></PHP:DataSource>');
?>
```

how to use p_split or other function that result

```
type=DataSource
attr=ID="DataSource1"
attr=CommandText="SELECT * FROM login"
attr=Adapter="Adapter1"
```

i try

```
function SplitTag($xstring) {
  $xsplit = array();
  $xsplit = preg_split("/\s+/", $xstring);
  print_r($xsplit);
}
```

but not work for attr=CommandText="SELECT * FROM login"

Comment: Does this question refer to Smarty ? It could be tagged that way.

Comment: what are you trying to do parse this line and call all the attributes ?

Comment: attr and type that name from adding

Comment: What's in $xstring, and how/why does SMARTTAG end up calling SplitTag?  You'll probably find the answer requires preg_match_all instead of preg_split - but it depends wtf you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a [simple XML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) parser for this?